# KDE Apps on Ubuntu 20.04 - Right Click Issue

Tags: gnome, 20.04, context-menu, kde-apps

I use Gnome desktop and depend on several KDE apps for my daily workflows. I have noticed that since migrating to a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, all KDE apps have an issue with the mouse right click (context menu). When I right click any kde app, it automatically selects the highlighted menu item and submits when I let go of the mouse button.

The expected behavior is to leave the context menu up when I let go of the mouse button and a left mouse click is required to select an item in the context menu.

Apps I have had this issue with: Kdenlive, Kfind, Konqueror, KDESVN

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by installing `kde-plasma-desktop` via the ppa `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`.

Add PPA:

```
% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

Update packages:

```
% sudo apt update
```

Install Package:

```
% sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop
```

When prompted to use Choose `gdm3` or `sddm`, choose `gdm3`.

Run an update post-install

```
% sudo apt update
```

Reboot the machine and log back into Ubuntu.

When you log in, try your regular desktop. When typing in password, gear will show on bottom right of screen, click on this to see desktop options. The standard for Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome is `Ubuntu`.

If you have issues logging into the desktop, you can type `ctrl-alt-F3` to get to a console to troubleshoot. Note that it may be required to do another `sudo apt-update` after logging back in, as this is how I had to resolve login issues, although I did not do the update after the initial install.

That should get this right click issue as well as many other KDE app issues resolved under Gnome. I noticed that all the apps now look correct, have proper context menu functionality and function much better in general.

Update 2020-07-21:
*My experience so far with initially installing `kubuntu-desktop` on the same machine as my Gnome Ubuntu has been bad as it broke my regular Ubuntu Gnome desktop. I'm now having to look at reverting back to the ZFS snapshot before the change as it pooched a bunch of functionality in Gnome. I hope to try again with `kde-plasma-desktop` after I survive that process (fingers crossed).*

Update 2020-07-22:
*Was able to revert the base system to before `kubuntu-desktop` was installed and subsequently installed `kde-plasma-desktop`. I can confirm that `kde-plasma-desktop` installation fixes issues with right click issues in KDE Apps. Note that `kde-plasma-desktop` itself was very large and the subsequent `apt update` took down a ton more changes. However, my Gnome desktop seems to be working well now alongside the KDE Apps.*